# How to get Angular app working in Wordpress plugin?

Tags: plugins, javascript

I am working on a project that requires Angular to be loaded in a Wordpress plugin, and am running into some snage getting it working. After some trial and error, the final error I ran into was:

```
main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1 ERROR Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at e.value (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at yi (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at ji (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at Ni (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at Object.Xi [as createRootView] (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at t.value (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at t.value (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at e.value (main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at main-es5.js?ver=5.3.2:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

The plugin code:

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Example
* Description: description
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Some guy
* Author URI: www.website.com
* Test Domain: pluginname
*/

wp_register_script( 'example_main5_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/main-es5.js', __FILE__));
wp_register_script( 'example_main2015_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/main-es2015.js', __FILE__));
// wp_register_script( 'example_poly5_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/polyfills-es5.js', __FILE__));
// wp_register_script( 'example_poly2015_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/polyfills-es2015.js', __FILE__));
wp_register_script( 'example_run5_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/runtime-es5.js', __FILE__));
wp_register_script( 'example_run2015_js', plugins_url('/hello-app/runtime-es2015.js', __FILE__));


function example_enqueue_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script('example_main5_js');
  wp_enqueue_script('example_main2015_js');
  // wp_enqueue_script('example_poly5_js');
  // wp_enqueue_script('example_poly2015_js');
  wp_enqueue_script('example_run5_js');
  wp_enqueue_script('example_run2015_js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'example_enqueue_script');



function example_test_function() {

echo '<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HelloApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>';
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'example_test_function');
?>
```

I have consulted with [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589738/angular2-error-the-selector-app-root-did-not-match-any-elements) on this topic, and everything is properly declared in the selector, etc, the pure Angular version of this works without issue in both production and development environment tests.

If I move the functions registering/enqueuing the scripts to inside the `example_test_function` function, the app-root error disappears from the console, but I'm still not seeing the app render on-screen as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was close here, but what needed to happen to make it work was to pass in `true` as an argument to the optional `in_footer` parameter like so:

`wp_enqueue_script('cbd_main5_js', '', [], false, true);`